# NSString: Find parts of string in another string

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I know how to find a string in another string, that is easy. But in this case I want to find John Smith within the allProfessors string. So I figured I could just split the string and search for both parts, which works how I want:

```
NSString *fullName = @"John Smith";
NSArray *parts = [fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *allProfessors = @"Smith, John; Clinton, Bill; Johnson, John";
NSRange range = [[allProfessors lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[[parts objectAtIndex:0] lowercaseString]];
NSRange range2 = [[allProfessors lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[[parts objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString]];
if(range.location != NSNotFound && range2.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Found");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not Found");
}
```

**What I want to know is, is this the BEST way to do this or is there a more preferred method to do what I want?**

In addition to this, what if my fullName is longer than my allProfessors name, such as:

```
NSString *fullName = @"Gregory Smith";
NSString *allProfessors = @"Smith, Greg; Clinton, Bill; Johnson, John";
```

I still want there to be a match for Greg Smith and Gregory Smith.

Comment: Best in terms of what?  Performance?  Maintainability?

Comment: It would be easier if allProfessors was an NSArray instead of an NSString. Then you could transpose fullName and search thru the array.

Comment: In terms of speed and just doing things the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions, which I prefer to use.  See [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/).

With RegexKitLite, you could use a regular expression **like** (untested):

```
NSString *regEx = @"(?i)Smith,\\s*\\w";
NSArray *matchingStrings = [allProfessors componentsMatchedByRegex:regEx];

if ([matchingStrings count] == 0)  // not found!
{
   [...]
}
else
{
   [...]
}
```

Using RegexKitLite you could alternatively have used [NSString stringByMatching:(NSString*)].

You can really do a lot with regular expression.  There are a ton of different functions available through [Using RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/#UsingRegexKitLite).  The regular expression above should find people with the last name of Smith.

Regular Expression explained:

- `(?i)`    make this case insensitive
- `Smith`   matches last name of Smith.  Obviously you could change this to anything
- `,`       match a comma
- `\\s*`    match any number of spaces (greedy)
- `\\w`     match a word

Also, you could use [[NSString rangeOfString:options:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_options_) function like:

```
if ([myString rangeOfString:@"John" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound &&
    [myString rangeOfString:@"Smith" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
{
   NSLog(@"Found");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Not Found");
}
```

Also see similar functions like [[rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW24) so that you can do case insensitive searches and even specify a locale.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you were looking for.  If not, perhaps I should be asking the same question as you!  :)  Anyways, hopefully this is remotely helpful and provides some new information.  If this is not useful, leave me a comment and I will remove it.  Regular expressions are truly awesome however.  They solve the dilemma of "pattern matching" nicely, but it may be overkill if you just want to see if a string contains another string.  We use the NSString rangeOfString:options: where I work.

Comment: And what do you return for "Bill Smith"?

Comment: @ott +1  I really should make my solution more flexible.

Comment: Sam, I just updated my question. Can you look at the last part I just added and let me know if you think regular expressions would help in this case?

Comment: If you want to match based on whether someone has a last name or not, then ya regular expression would work great.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I am going with your regex solution.